# Вывести текст из input в поле <p>?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как вывести текст из `input` в другой блок или параграф ?

Comment: а их нельзя по разным блокам сделать?

Answer (score 5):

```js
$('.pole').keyup(function() {
  var val = $('.pole').val();//Получаем данные из input
  $('.txt').html(val);//Вставляем значение в тег с классом txt
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="pole" type="text">
<p class="txt"></p>
```

Comment: а то это типа фишка в vue :))

Comment: vue? вы не указали в задание про vue. Метки js и jquery

Comment: нет ! вы не поняли меня -я не автор вопроса , просто vue постоянно это везде показывает типа это такая фишка ... + от меня

Comment: @Максим Ленский, да, точно, не вы автор, сорри))

Answer (score 3):

Вот решение на чистом `JS`

```js
function input() {
  var input_taker = document.getElementById('input').value;
  document.getElementById('block').innerHTML = input_taker;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input" onkeyup="input()">
<p id="block"></p>
```

Answer (score 3):

> Как вывести текст из input в другой блок или параграф ?

```js
var input = document.querySelector('input')
// Вешаем обработчик события на инпут
input.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
  // Выбираем р
  var p = document.querySelector('.res')
  p.textContent = e.target.value
})
```

```html
<input type="text" name="w">
<p class='res'>
<!-------- Выводим -------->
</p>
```

П.С. Для полного набора в коллекцию

Answer (score 2):

Еще есть такой вариант!

```js
$('.pole').on('input', function() {
  var val = $('.pole').val();//Получаем данные из input
  $('.txt').html(val);//Вставляем значение в тег с классом txt
$('.txt').val(val);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="pole" type="text">
<p class="txt"></p>
<a class="txt"></a><br>
<span class="txt"></span><br>
<input type="text" class="txt">
```

Comment: Это больше похоже на фишку Vue.js

Comment: Единственный ответ, где событие `input`, а не `keyup`. Плюс от меня)

Answer (score 2):

> Тег `output` определяет область в которую выводится информация

Похоже последний вариант для коллекции:

```html
<form oninput="result.value=text.value">
  <p><input type="text" name="text" autofocus></p>
  <p><output name="result"></output></p>
</form>
```

Comment: Очень хорошее решение, простое и доступное. Я бы до такого не додумался. Спасибо !